# How do I get an image from the iOS photo library and display it in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I've seen a lot of examples where you use the `UIImage` for outputting an image. I would like the output to be set to a `UIWebView` because I want to put some additional HTML formatting around the image.

I want to get the photo library to return the relative path of an image stored on the iOS device, so that the I can put that in the 'src' attribute of the 'img' HTML tag.

Is this possible?

---

Edit 1

I had to modify my code for what I wanted but this doesn't seem to work.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //Get Image URL from Library
    NSURL *urlPath = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSString *urlString = [urlPath absoluteString];
    NSLog(urlString);

    NSURL *root = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
    NSString *html;
    html = @"<img src='";
    html = [html stringByAppendingString:urlString];
    html = [html stringByAppendingString:@"' />"];
    [MemeCanvas loadHTMLString:html baseURL:root];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

I am able to log the asset-library URL but it doesn't seem to be displayed the image on the `UIWebView`. I don't know what I need to change the baseURL to.

Any help appreciated.

---

Edit 2

I changed `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` to `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` and now it crashes because it doesnt like it when i append it to a string with `stringByAppendingString:urlString`

It gives me the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString
>   stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'

Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: how about use TextKit if you just layout some string content around the image.and thanks @rokjarc for sharing a good question.

Comment: You need the file URL, not the assets-library URL.  Change `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` to `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[**Updated to swift 4**]
You can use `UIImagePickerController` delegate to select the image (or url) you want to edit.

you can do this like this:

```
let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
pickerController.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: {
})
```

in the delegate implementation you can use the path of the image or the image itself:

```
// This method is called when an image has been chosen from the library or taken from the camera.

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {    
   //You can retrieve the actual UIImage
   let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
   //Or you can get the image url from AssetsLibrary
   let path = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL
   picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: if i used camera to capture photo then `[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];` gives me (null) value.. any solutions for that ?

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var pickedImage:UIImage?

    @IBAction func ActionChooseImage(sender:UIButton){
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        self.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        self.pickedImage = image

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37996619/3411787)

Answer (score 4):

**Updated for Swift 3.0**

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
imagePickerController.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And the delegate:

```
extension YourViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        // Whatever you want here
        self.pickedImage = image
        picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load Image from Photolibrary into webview as shown below code

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info    
       {
      NSURL *urlPath = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
      UIImage *cameraImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
      NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cameraImage);
      [self.webview loadData:myData MIMEType:@"image/png" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
      [self.picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you have to conform to protocol `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

```
UIImagePickerController *myImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        myImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        myImagePicker.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:myImagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Load an Image & then Show in WebView.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //Get Image URL from Library
    NSURL *urlPath = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlPath];
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: This still provides the assets-library URL, and you're removing all the HTML which is what the OP wanted.